# String equivalent in mysql datatypes

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a create a column that needs to store unknown length strings.

I am making a parsing of some file and pushing it's content to the DB and I have no idea about the length , can be pretty big.

So is there any equivalent to String type ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on what your storing...

- CHAR is a fixed length string
- VARCHAR is a variable length string
- TINYTEXT/TEXT/MEDIUMTEXT/LONGTEXT is a text field (long string)

Choose the format that is most appropriate for what your storing.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html for more information on the TEXT field and the differences.

Comment: I need a dynamic growing string type

Comment: You can store as little or as much as you want within the limits of the space allocated for the string for all of those formats, LONGTEXT can store an enormous amount of data for example, but is less efficient as the database has to do more to use it.

Comment: This may also prove helpful - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html